# release laravel project from VSTS to Azure to the correct folder

Tags: laravel, azure, path, azure-devops, release

I am using Visual Studio Team Services to release my LARAVEL Project to Azure.
On the Azure application setting and by default to virtual directory it sets :
"**/**" as "**site\wwwroot**" (1)

But with the Laravel Framework the application is accessible from "http://PATH\public"
When I set "/" as "site\wwwroot\public" I can access to my application.

But if I made a new release, I have to remove "public" from the path setting (1) during the release and add it after.
If I am not doing that, the new release will be published at "site\wwwroot\public\public"

I would like to automate the process and not every release, have to remove "public" and add it after

I have tested also a Azure powershell task but it is not working.
Does anyone as solution to share please ?

Comment: How do you publish your project? Through Azure App Service Deploy task? What's the folder structure of project package that used to deploy?

Comment: Thank you for support, I Publish the project from VSTS to Azure using the Azure App Service Deploy task. I use my folder development, it a parent folder from my LARAVEL framework php project.

Comment: Where do you remove "public" from the path setting? Is there a public folder in the parent folder of the project? Can you share the detail log of Azure App Service Deploy task on the OneDrive?

Comment: Hello, Laravel framework working by displaying content from "public" folder. In Azure virtual repository I have : "\" as "site\wwwroot\public". If I would like to release my application from VSTS to AZURE I had to remove the "public" from the Azure "/" virtual repository. After the release I had to add  "public" on the "/" virtual repository value to see the content because Laravel working like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for reply. 
I did it but no it this way :

1. Go to `AZURE -> APPLICATION ->   APPLICATION SETTINGS`,
2. I set virtual directory with virtual path :
   `/myApplication` to `site\wwwroot`& `/` to `site\wwwroot\public.`
3. Go to `VSTS`, on the release option, on the `Deploy Azure App Service` task
4. I set virtual application to `/myApplication`, and it is working well !

Comment: Did this actually work? Because the files are outside of the webroot so they can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Log on azure > Select your App Service > Application settings
2. Add a new virtual application or directory in Virtual applications and directories (Virtual path: `/public`; physical path: `site\wwwroot\public`; Check `Application option`)
3. Edit your build/release definition
4. Select `Azure App Service Deploy` task and specify `public` in Virtual application input box (Package or folder: `{project runtime files path}`)